# Error while accessing API v2 from thetvdb.com [Python requests. Error 403 ]

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to access the API v2 from [thetvdb.com](https://api.thetvdb.com). Unfortunately I always get the 403 error.

Here is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests

url = "https://api.thetvdb.com/login"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = {"apikey":"123","username":"secretusername","userkey":"123"}
post = requests.post(url, data = payload, headers = headers)
print(post.status_code, post.reason)
```

According to the API documentation I have to authenticate in order to get a token. But I just get 403 Forbidden.

Now I tried it using curl:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: 
application/json' -d  
{"apikey":"123","username":"secretusername","userkey":"123"}' 
'https://api.thetvdb.com/login'
```

And this worked perfectly. Can anyone explain me what I am missing? This is driving me insane.

I also tried it with

```
post = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers = headers)
```

Same error.

Comment: try replacing the url with a `http://requestb.in` URL and do both python and curl request . Then in browser you can see what was different in yor requests here is how you may use that `https://exotel.in/blog/engineering/debugging-your-exotel-webhooks-more-efficiently-using-requestbin/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `explicitly` convert the `payload` to json string and pass as`data` . It looks like you have done that also you may try setting the user-agent as `curl/7.47.1`

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.47.1'}
post = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers = headers)
```

The program will look like

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
import json    

url = "https://api.thetvdb.com/login"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.47.1'}
payload = {"apikey":"123","username":"secretusername","userkey":"123"}
post = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers = headers)
print(post.status_code, post.reason)
```

Comment: @Andersson if curl is working this must work. Only possible check that the server might be doing is it may check for "UserAgent"

Comment: The worked. Thanks to @Sarathsp and requestb.in I found out that the only difference between Python and Curl was the User-Agent. I changed it to curl and it worked.

Comment: @Sarathsp I did. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass Accept headers in the python requests. Something like this:

```
header = {
        'Accept' : 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "User-Agent": "some user-agent",
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    url = 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/'
    payload = {}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.47.1'}
   #headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
   response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, 
   verify='/installed/aws/usr/lib/python2.7/site- 
   packages/certifi/cacert.pem', timeout=5)
   instance_profile_role_name = response.text
   print response.text`
```

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue and I tried using the agent and it wont resolve the problem. so basically I am aws and trying to do a curl to read the metadata, that works well. However when I try to use requests.post it gives me : <Response [403]> (403, 'Forbidden'). Here is my code. @Sarath Sadasivan Pillai any suggestions?

Comment: This is a new question, not another answer. It has the same problem as the original, which is that payload isn't first converted into a json string.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30153614)