# 403 error with BeautifulSoup on specific site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape https://www.vitals.com/locations/primary-care-doctors/ny. I have been able to scrape other sites by editing my headers, but I keep getting a 403 error with this one.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with requests.Session() as se:
    se.headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    }


test_sites = [
 'http://fashiontoast.com/',
 'https://www.vitals.com/locations/primary-care-doctors/ny',
 'http://www.seaofshoes.com/',
 ]

for site in test_sites:
    print(site)
    #get page soure
    response = se.get(site)
    print(response)
    #print(response.text)
```

Comment: I just ran your code and I got all 200 resp
https://www.vitals.com/locations/primary-care-doctors/ny
<Response [200]>

Comment: Any ideas what could be causing different results? I'm still getting a 403 error.

Comment: Can you try removing the s from https and try again

Comment: I still receive the same error when removing the s.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the code to the `with` statement as follows

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with requests.Session() as se:
    se.headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    }

    test_sites = [
     'http://fashiontoast.com/',
     'https://www.vitals.com/locations/primary-care-doctors/ny',
     'http://www.seaofshoes.com/',
     ]

    for site in test_sites:
        print(site)
        #get page soure
        response = se.get(site)
        print(response)
        #print(response.text)
```

Comment: I still receive the same responses.

Comment: I'm not too sure why you're getting this issue still, this question was asked multiple times and adding user agent tend to solve it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946166/requests-get-returns-403-while-the-same-url-works-in-browser
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086383/python-requests-403-forbidden-despite-setting-user-agent-headers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361444/python-requests-error-403
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930720/python-requests-html-403-response

Comment: I followed the advice in some of the links and tried adding additional headers such as referer but still receive these error messages in response:

title>Access denied | www.vitals.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /

 <h2 data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.</